# start the day over

Tags: phrase-meaning

Please, explain what "over" in bold is meaning. I looked in the dictionary but couldn't choose proper meaning. The text is:

> "I'm sorry, kids," Officer Flanagan said. "Your mother was killed."
>
> Kate's eyes grew wide, and she began to shake and then cry. Chad wished he could cry. He wanted to reach over and hold Kate, but he couldn't move. This had to be a bad dream. He would wake up soon and start the day **over**.

Comment: What definitions did you find and why don't you think they fit?

Answer (score -1):

Looking up just **over** will not give you a satisfactory interpretation because it is being used here as a *phrasal verb*. If you look up [**start over**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/start-over) instead you get:

> ## Start Over
>
> **to begin to do something again, sometimes in a different way:**
>
> > *We decided to abandon the first draft of the report and start over.*

This meaning is being used in your sentence even though it is split by "the day." Another not as common way could be

> "He would wake up soon and *start over* the day"

Comment: Just to clarify, "start over the day" would be *very* uncommon, to the point of almost being wrong.

Comment: The statement that looking up the word *over* itself won't help, and that this is only a phrasal verb, is wrong. (In fact, that thinking leads to the wrong additional sentence you propose.) In the sentence in the question, **over** means the same thing as **again**, which is exactly one of the senses defined in [dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over): "once more : AGAIN // do it *over* // Let's start *over* from the beginning."